# how to evaluate a xpath without considing the empty Text node using JDom2

Tags: dom, xpath, implementation, jdom-2

For an xml segment:

```
<tr>
  <td>
   Price:
  </td>
  <td>
      <span>
         <b>
           $11.85
         </b>
      </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

when I evaluate the xpath:
`//text()[preceding::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][position()=1][normalize-space()='Price:']]` , the result is :

```
[ 
]
[

]
[ 

]
[ 
$11.85
]
```

but I only want to find the `[$11.85]`. So what can I do to evaluate a xpath without considering the empty text node?

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPATH to get $11.85:

```
//text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][ancestor::td/preceding-sibling::td[1][normalize-space(.)='Price:']]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But in my real situation, I want to get text $11.85 based on the preceding-sibling Text node "Price".